# Can I make ssh-agent wait until I use ssh to prompt for a password?

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, ssh-agent

I have ssh-agent set up to automatically start and prompt when I open a terminal window, as is explained [here](http://help.github.com/working-with-key-passphrases/). It gets somewhat annoying though since many times when I open a shell I don't plan on using ssh for anything. Is there a way to delay this password prompt until I try to use ssh?

In other words, the first time I use SSH I want a password prompt, all subsequent times I don't want one, and I don't want one if I'm not about to use SSH.

Comment: Quality answer have emerged since this was asked: https://superuser.com/a/1114257/467870

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to write (or find) an agent proxy that would detect absence of the key in the agent and prompt for the passphrase when the key is requested, then load the key into the real agent.

Comment: Sounds like a weekend project to me.

Comment: So, have you implemented it?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24347344/4573065 + its comments for a good way to acieve this.